# log4j in Eclipse doesn't print anything above info() despite loglevel being TRACE

Tags: java, eclipse, log4j

For some reason, my log4j logger only prints `info()` lines to the Console in eclipse, even though the logger was explicitly switched to TRACE level.

I confirmed the above by printing:

```
logger.info("Log level: " + logger.getLevel()
           + " ;effective level: " + logger.getEffectiveLevel()
           + " ;isTraceEnabled: " + logger.isTraceEnabled());
```

Which gave me

```
INFO  2016-07-20 15:57:21,391 [pool-10-thread-1] MyClass  
- Log level: TRACE ;effective level: TRACE ;isTraceEnabled: true
```

However, in the subsequent lines, the following doesn't get printed to Console:

```
logger.trace("TEST TRACE");
logger.debug("TEST DEBUG");
```

I am guessing this isn't a case of properties file being wrong since I explicitly set the logger loglevel to TRACE elesewhere in the code.

Comment: Probably because the `ConsoleAppender` filters anything below INFO. Look at your Log4j configuration file.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.

Log4j.xml had this:

```
 <appender  name="default" class="my.wrapper.class.Log4JAppender">
      <param name="Threshold" value="INFO" />
```

Had to change the Threshold to TRACE

```
      <param name="Threshold" value="TRACE" />
```